# Nginx: reverse proxy Influxdb can't find static files

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, influxdb

I have a setup where I have multiple service running with docker compose and one Nginx (nginx:1.19-alpine), which acts as a reverse proxy for all services and serves some static files.

One service is an Influxdb container (influxdb:2.1.0-alpine) which provides a UI for webbrowsers.
I want to reverse proxy to this container, but I get problems with the static files of this container.

This would be my rule so far:

```
upstream database {
    server data-db:8086;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location /influx/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://database/;
    }
}
```

I get a white screen, when I browse to http://localhost:8080/influx/ (localhost:8080 is the Nginx)
The console shows me, that the static files cannot be found.

[image]

In the image you can see, that the browser tries to find files at / and not /influx/. That's a problem, because I have other things on /
I've seen similar questions, but can't get my setup to run properly.

Comment: There is a ton of similar questions at SF and SO (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649885/a-little-confused-about-trailing-slash-behavior-in-nginx), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759345/nginx-trailing-slash-in-proxy-pass-url)). Remove the trailing slash from `proxy_pass http://database/;` directive.

Comment: I tried that and I get the same results.

Comment: It should work. Maybe something get cached? Try from the incognito window.

Comment: I tried incognito window and a different browser. I thought that this should work, but somehow it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is not an real answer to this. I found this two year old Github issue: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/15721
It is a known problem, but wasn't fixed as of now.

A workaround could be to use subdomains, so you can serve Influx on a root directory like influx.example.com/
For hosting on localhost one would have to add an entry to the hosts file and  add that "domain" to the server directive of nginx.